# Background colour is not covering all of the page in ReactJS/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles

I have set the background in html body as below (ReactJS) it is covering the main screen size but if .map function has large number of items i.e i have to scroll down then it is not showing for that part of the screen (bottom), i cant think of a reason why it is doing this . any thoughts please.

-`Background` color set in the index.html file

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(198, 201, 204);" class="rootdiv" id="root"></div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you apply the colour to the body itself?

Answer (score 0):

try setting height in 100vh in css

Answer (score 0):

in your container div (where you map your items inside it) add this:

```
max-height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in ur background style height: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is probably because the color is only covering the screen that shows when page loads. The remain page that is not shown, in which you had to scrool down, are not rendered with the same background...
So one idea is to cover the color in all height.

```
min-height: 100%;
```